# Clear Chrome's cache via CLI

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome, terminal, cache

Is there a way to clear Google Chrome's cache via a CLI command on OSX? Ideally this would be made via some “official” way, and preferably without having to open Chrome (i.e. by launching it with some flags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to delete Google Chrome's cache is to delete the cache directory.

Chrome 23's cache is split into two directories:

- `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache` (web browsing)
- `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Media Cache` (videos, music, etc.)

To clear the cache, it would suffice to execute the following command:

```
rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/*
```

Change **Default** to your user profile's name if you have created one.

Comment: I thought so, unfortunately. Well, anyway, on OSX there's `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/`.

Comment: Does this still hold true for Chrome 42?