# Clear (or bypass) cache on Chromium startup

Tags: google-chrome, cache, chromium, browser-cache

How to clear the Chromium cache on startup, via Chrome command-line arguments?

I have already read [Clear Chrome's cache via CLI](https://superuser.com/questions/523202/clear-chromes-cache-via-cli) but the goal is slightly different.

I need Chromium (embedded) to bypass CSS files and JS files cache on startup and use new files if they have been modified.

Usually I need to manually <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  <kbd>F5</kbd> after each CSS+JS files modification, even after a Chromium relaunch (without it, it doesn't update), and I'd like to avoid this because it's an embedded computer without keyboard.

Comment: What platform? Ctrl/F5 suggests Windows but your linked question is on Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes Windows. If possible, I would like to avoid to have to manually mingle with the filesystem cache folder.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome does not have a specific
[command-line switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
for clearing the cache.

A simple solution might be to specify your own cache folder, rather
than letting Chrome use its default, and delete the contents of the
folder before running it.

The parameter is similar to : `--disk-cache-dir="C:\Temp"`.

To delete all files and sub-folders inside the folders,
you could use the following `.bat` file:

```
del /q "C:\Temp\*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Temp\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

Note that `del` by itself is not enough, since it only deletes
files and not sub-folders, which is why `rmdir` is required.
You could also add the Chrome invocation at the end of the file.

Comment: I think you meant Google Chrome, rather than Chromium.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good solution! Would it also be possible to totally disable cache, from command-line?

Comment: I would have said to set `--disk-cache-size=0`, except for this 2015 bug-report [Issue 447590: --disk-cache-size=0 --media-cache-size=0 options are not respected](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447590) that has as status "WontFix". If nothing has changed since then, then the batch file is left as the solution.

Comment: Thank you @harrymc. Do you think there is a way to disable cache from Chrome User Settings ? or chrome://settings ?

Comment: I haven't found any.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. So there is no way at all to disable Chrome cache? (except in the Developer tools, but then it will only work when Developer tools panel is open which is not what I want)

Comment: That's the situation as far as I know.